# laravel showing file structure and after that this error

Tags: laravel

[laravel installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xbYW.png)

i am getting this error,when i typed localhost/myproject it gave me directory structure and when i go to public /index.php it gave me above error

Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Comment: Do you have a file missing? `No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17`

Comment: update your composer using `composer update` commmand and create a virtual host for your project or use `serve` command to run your project on localhost

Comment: updated the composer @raushan but not worked

Comment: Did you run `composer install`? That command creates the autoload file which is missing.

Comment: i have to run composer install command on my project directory?

Comment: had following error when i try to install composer on project

Comment: pranav@pranav-hp-notebook:/opt/lampp/htdocs/test$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Comment: Do you have vendor in Directory ?  try to update your composer